# Find all tags with a specific attribute value

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

How can I iterate over all tags which have a specific attribute with a specific value? For instance, let's say we need the data1, data2 etc... only.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <invalid html here/>
        <dont care> ... </dont care>
        <invalid html here too/>
        <interesting attrib1="naah, it is not this"> ... </interesting tag>
        <interesting attrib1="yes, this is what we want">
            <group>
                <line>
                    data
                </line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    data1
                <line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    data2
                <line>
            </group>
        </interesting>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried BeautifulSoup but it can't parse the file. lxml's parser, though, seems to work:

```
broken_html = get_sanitized_data(SITE)

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(broken_html), parser)

result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method="html")

print(result)
```

I am not familiar with its API, and I could not figure out how to use either getiterator or xpath.

Comment: Did you try changing the MIME-type to XML? some parsers are picky...

Comment: With lxml using xpath seems to be pretty easy, give the docs a chance :) http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, using lxml and the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) `'descendant::*[@attrib1="yes, this is what we want"]'`. The XPath tells lxml to look at all the descendants of the current node and return those with an `attrib1` attribute equal to `"yes, this is what we want"`.

```
import lxml.html as lh 
import cStringIO

content='''
<html>
    <body>
        <invalid html here/>
        <dont care> ... </dont care>
        <invalid html here too/>
        <interesting attrib1="naah, it is not this"> ... </interesting tag>
        <interesting attrib1="yes, this is what we want">
            <group>
                <line>
                    data
                </line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    data1
                <line>
            </group>
            <group>
                <line>
                    data2
                <line>
            </group>
        </interesting>
    </body>
</html>
'''
doc=lh.parse(cStringIO.StringIO(content))
tags=doc.xpath('descendant::*[@attrib1="yes, this is what we want"]')
print(tags)
# [<Element interesting at b767e14c>]
for tag in tags:
    print(lh.tostring(tag))
# <interesting attrib1="yes, this is what we want"><group><line>
#                     data
#                 </line></group><group><line>
#                     data1
#                 <line></line></line></group><group><line>
#                     data2
#                 <line></line></line></group></interesting>
```